# Resize images by css

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

I use the following css to display many images by one request

```
div.image1{
   backgroud:url(image.png) -100px -2px no-repeat;
   width:80px;
   height:60px
}
```

but to make my website friendly to different monitor resolutions, I might need to resize it, but when I change it's width and height the image look bad and not in full resolution.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px){
   div.image1{
       width:60px;
       height:44px
    }
}
```

Now if screen is lower than 880px it will display just 60x44 resolution image and not the full image

How do I make it like a normal `<img />` tag which when I change the width and height it doesn't look bad

Comment: You're probably looking for the [CSS 3 background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) i read `img { max-width: 100%; }` , thats all you need to add i guess. Also you can select the image by `<img src="smallRes.jpg" data-fullsrc="largeRes.jpg">`

Comment: what about `background-size` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try the following properties combined with media query:

```
.image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}

.image1 {
  background-image: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7405/26324518664_0d4e70e511_n.jpg');
}

.image2 {
  background-image: url('http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7149/26855282121_fb57a99f0c_n.jpg');
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 880px){
  .image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px
  }
  .image1 {
    background-image: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7405/26324518664_0d4e70e511_s.jpg');
  }
  .image2 {
    background-image: url('http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7149/26855282121_fb57a99f0c_s.jpg');
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/1umatrtz/